# How does iOS identify received notification is for MDM?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I want to use MDM to manage number of iOS devices.

According to documentation I do not need anything installed on device. In that case when device receives a notification from APNS server, how will it come to know that this notificaation is for MDM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push Notification String: `{"aps":{},"mdm":"MagicPushDeviceCode"}`.

Comment: I tried using 
    
    $payload['aps'] = array();
    $payload['mdm'] = 'ASamplePushMagicString';
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

I have a php file in server url of my configuration profile which creates and writes the response to a txt file. But after pushing the payload nothing happens.. :(

Please help

Answer (score 4):

You need to install at least a root certificate from the MDM-Company (in your case your software / yourself need to deploy the root certificate to the endusers device).
As soon as the device has the root certificate installed, you can send some MDM json payloads through APNS.

I think you can deploy the root certificate with many ways including download in safari on your iOS or also with the configuration utility.